# What is the soundtrack playing when Luffy beats 50 thousand enemies with Conqueror's Haki on Fishman Island?

Tags: one-piece, music

I am just looking for the soundtrack that was being played when Luffy defeats 50 thousand enemies with Conqueror's Haki on Fishman Island in episode 554.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Sai, sai, saikyou!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WT3a5C16oac)